# What is meant with Keyboard reconstruction?

Tags: theory

In a question about the program of music theory I read the term *keyboard reconstruction*.[link](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82027/largely-self-teaching-for-grade-8-music-theory-abrsm-any-recommended-resourc)

What does it mean?

Comment: https://www.mymusictheory.com/learn-music-theory/for-students/grade-8-music-theory/grade-8-keyboard-reconstruction

Comment: coult it also mean play thorough bass?

Answer (score 2):

He is referring to the ABRSM Theory syllabus, Grade 8.

https://us.abrsm.org/fileadmin/user_upload/syllabuses/theory0810.pdf

I think 'Keyboard reconstruction' may be a corruption of 'keyboard realization'.

"Continuation of a given opening of a passage from a Baroque trio sonata for two treble instruments and basso continuo. The basso continuo part will be given throughout and fully figured (but a realization for keyboard will not be required)."

I also see the possibility if it being a corruption of some other part of the syllabus.   It may be that @Lenna, the original questioner, is confused over the requirements. So it's pointless to analyse his description of them too rigorously.

Comment: The link I posted in a comment suggests keyboard reconstruction is about "following the style of the given material to write something which fits convincingly". So you get a piece with a part missing, and you have to "reconstruct" the missing part.

Comment: *(but a realization for keyboard will not be required).* Exactly this task would make sense - but this isn‘t required. So it is to set tha bass line to a given tune, or the opposie? Or is the term only regarding the trio sonate to complete the missing part adding it to 2 others?

Comment: @YourUncleBob Continuo parts are improvised, so there is no original score to reconstruct, hence the term ' reconstruct' doesn't seem to make sense in this sentence.